# Project build fails after adding MonkeyTalk iOS agent to target build in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

I have added the iOS agent to a project in XCode 4.5. The build fails with the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
+[MPMovieView(MTReady) load] in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPFullScreenTransportControls", referenced from:
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPFullScreenTransportControls_$_MTDisable in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPFullScreenVideoOverlay", referenced from:
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPFullScreenVideoOverlay_$_MTDisable in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMovieView", referenced from:
anon in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPMovieView_$_MTReady in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPSwipableView", referenced from:
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPSwipableView_$_MTDisable in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPTransportButton", referenced from:
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPTransportButton_$_MTDisable in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPVideoBackgroundView", referenced from:
l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MPVideoBackgroundView_$_MTDisable in libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a(MPMovieView+MTReady.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone help me out. The build without the iOS agent builds fine.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like there are dependent frameworks you did not add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to link in `MediaPlayer.framework`.

Comment: Thank you sir.  That was the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the MediaPlayer framework already, you probably do not need to link in the libMonkeyTalkMediaPlayer-1.0.24.a library - you should only need the libMonkeyTalk-1.0.24.a library.

As you probably know already, the basic instructions for linking the libMonkeyTalk-1.0.xx.a library are [here](http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/ios).